# Python3.10 installation on CentOS7 results in a different file type

Tags: python-3.x, installation, centos7

I was trying to install python3.10 on CentOS7 by following [This Guide](https://linuxstans.com/how-to-install-python-centos/)

However, even after following the steps, I still can't use python3.10. After investigating /usr/local/bin, I found out that the python3 file (which comes preinstalled) have a different file type compared to the installed python3.10 (can be seen from the different color below)

[The Image (I can't add image yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhPE9.png)

Is there a way to fix this or am I missing some steps?

Edit: if it helps, it seems that the color of python3.10 is the same as a python3 module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it turns out that I needed to create a symlink on /usr/bin. So to fix this I run the following command on the terminal

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin
```

Afterwards I can use the command python3.10